# Search the 7 elements from the list using with the value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got the list of elements in `channels_list` and I want to find the next 7 channels from the list apart from `101 BBC One S East` so I can fetch the next 7 channels ahead.

Example: I have `101 BBC One S East`, so I want to find the 7 channels which it is `'108 Sky Atlantic'` so I can start from there to fetch the next 7 channels which it is `'108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ'`.

Here is the code:

```
channels_list = ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']

find_channel = '101 BBC One S East'

for i, start_ch in enumerate(self.channel):
    if start_ch == channel:
       channels_list = self.channel
```

Can you please show me an example how I can find the 7 channels from the list so I can fetch the next 7 channels using with the value??

**EDIT: Here it is:**

```
self.channels_Index += 7

for i, start_ch in enumerate(self.channel):
    if start_ch == channel:
        my_seven_channels = self.channel[i+self.channels_Index:i+14]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, first you need to make sure your code is using those values. I am going to assume they got lost while porting the code to Stack Overflow, but just in case... make sure of this changes.

1. Your list is named `channels_list`, but your enumerate tries to enumerate `self.channel`. Fix that.
2. Your code to find the channel doesn't uses the `find_channel` variable.

**Now about the real question:**
Enumerate saves the index of an item and its value, so once you find the desired item, you tell to the list *"get items from this index... to this index + 7 more"*. To do that we slice it using [from:to].

Code:

```
channels_list = ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']

find_channel = '101 BBC One S East'

for i, start_ch in enumerate(channels_list):
    if start_ch == find_channel:
       my_seven_channels = channels_list[i:i+7] 

print(my_seven_channels)
```

**Update:** After re-reading your question I think you confused us asking to get the next 7 items but instead you want to skip the next 7 items.

```
my_seven_channels = channels_list[i+7:i+14]
```

**Update 2:** Seems like there is a confussion with what `i` means so let me clarify it. i was just the name we assigned to the index. The next code works to first skip 7 items and then get the next 14 items, using as start point the `find_channel` variable.

```
for channel_index, start_ch in enumerate(channels_list):
    if start_ch == find_channel:
       my_seven_channels = channels_list[channel_index+7:channel_index + 21]
```

Comment: thank you very much for this but it look the same as my current code which show `['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living']`. I want to get something is like `['108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ']`. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: then just edit the find_channel value. As per your question you used `101 BBC One S East`. That's the first item that it will look for. If you use instead `find_channel = '108 Sky Atlantic'` take a guess on what it happens. Feel free to play with the code a bit, it's how you'll learn about slicing.

Comment: I have tried it with `my_seven_channels = channels_list[i:i+14]` which it will show 14 channels so it is incorrect. I want to find the 7 channel which it is `108 Sky Atlantic` to start from there then get the next 7 channels which it is `'108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ'`. Any idea?

Comment: See my update. The syntax is pretty much `[from:to]` so you can do [i+7:i+14] which basically means "from item 7 to 14".

Comment: Thank you very much for this, so how I can add another 7 channels after the `'406 Sky Sports News HQ'` to get the `'407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK'` when I am using `my_seven_channels = self.channel[i+self.channels_Index:i+14]`?

Comment: Well at this point, I think you want to first find a channel, then skip 7 channels, then get the next 14 channels, correct? That would be [i+7:i+21]. Note that i IS the channels index, we just used i to make it simple, but it could be named anything. I will update my code to reflect that.

Comment: No you have got it wrong. I want to skip the 7 channels to get the 7 next channels when I use `self.channels_index += 7` in each time when I add it up. So how I can skip the 7 channels to get the next 7 channels from the list?

Comment: Like this: when `self.channels_index` have the 7 values so I want to get `'108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ'`, when `self.channels_index` have the 14 values I want to get `'407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK'`and so on.....how?

Comment: At that point it's better if you just create a new list and append values as you need them. See documentation for append: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: You tell me to read the document when you are not helping me? i am very not very grateful of your response!

Comment: Dude, you don't even know how to explain what you need, and every approach I take to help you leads to another question. Please take a moment to understand what exactly is what you need, how to make sure we understand the issue and then maybe ask for help. Otherwise you are wasting both of our time. No offense intended.

Comment: I mean, is quite... confussing what you need. `[i+self.channels_Index:i+self.channels_Index+7]` ...?

Comment: I have already explained what I want. I want to skip the 7 channels to get the 7 channels from the list. I want to skip the 7 channels to get the 7 channels each time when I press on the keyboard. I hope you get this now what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: you want to get a variable number of items depending on a variable, not 7. We can easily hardcode a number 7 but is not the same if you want to change that 7 for a 14 instead. Hope you understand. See my last comment, I think that might do it.

Comment: This is what I want `[i+self.channels_Index:i+self.channels_Index+7]`. Thank you very much for this, problem are now solved!

Comment: My apologies if I was a bit rude. Needed to make sure you are self-aware of how confussing it was. Took me a lot to figure out what it was asked xD. Please remember to mark the answer as valid if it helped.

Comment: No problem and my apologies that I did not explained properly. I have mark the answer as valid. :)